# Select from python enum by member value

Tags: python, enums

How can I get all instances of a enum class that fulfill a criterion on a given, but unknown field?

I have the following three classes deriving from `Enum`, two simple ones (`VariableType` and `VariableCategory`) and one, in which the instances actually store content in fields (`Variable`).

```py
class VariableCategory(Enum):
    SHORT = auto()
    MEDIUM = auto()
    LONG = auto()

class VariableType(Enum):
    ONE = auto()
    TWO = auto()

class Variable(Enum):
    A = ('Variable A',
           VariableCategory.SHORT,
           VariableType.ONE,
           1)
    B = ('Variable B',
           VariableCategory.MEDIUM,
           VariableType.TWO,
           2)
    C = ('Variable V',
           VariableCategory.SHORT,
           VariableType.TWO,
           3)

    def __init__(self, name: str, variable_category: VariableCategory, variable_type: VariableType,
                 number:int) -> None:
        self.name = name
        self.variable_category = variable_category
        self.variable_type = variable_type
        self.number = number
```

Now, I would like to create a class function, that can take an arbitrary parameter of types `VariableType` or `VariableCategory` and return all corresponding instances of `Variable`:

```py
@classmethod
def by_x(cls, x: Union[VariableType, VariableCategory]):
    # something like return [cls[member] for member in cls.__members__ if x in cls[member]]
```

For example, given a `VariableType` the according instances of `Variable`, as in:

```py
>>> Variable.by_x(VariableType.ONE)
    [Variable.A]
>>> Variable.by_x(VariableType.TWO)
    [Variable.B, Variable.C]
>>> Variable.by_x(VariableCategory.SHORT)
    [Variable.A, Variable.C]
>>> Variable.by_x(VariableCategory.MEDIUM)
    [Variable.B]
>>> Variable.by_x(VariableCategory.LONG)
    []
```

I also know, that I can use more specific functions for one of the fields of the `Variable` enum:

```py
@classmethod
def by_variable_type(cls, variable_type: VariableType) -> List['Variable']:
    return [cls[member] for member in cls.__members__ if cls[member].variable_type == variable_type]
```

However, I do not known, how to make just one, generic function instead of many specific ones (that is, without checking the type of the parameter and calling the specific solution accordingly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution does what you want.

The `get_by_values` class method can receive a list, or list of lists with any combination of values you want satisfied. It guarantees to only return members that fully satisfied one of the combinations you passed in. It returns a `set` of `Enum` members, so guaranteeing there aren't any repetitions. If you used a list in the return, you would get ordered results corresponding to every argument you passed in.

`Variable` members already have `Variable.name` you declare them with. In case you want something more expressive I'd go with `__str__` or `__init__`, perhaps combining with `VariableCategory.name` and `VariableType.name`.

```py
from enum import Enum, auto


class VariableCategory(Enum):
    SHORT = auto()
    MEDIUM = auto()
    LONG = auto()


class VariableType(Enum):
    ONE = auto()
    TWO = auto()


class Variable(Enum):
    A = VariableCategory.SHORT, VariableType.ONE
    B = VariableCategory.MEDIUM, VariableType.TWO
    C = VariableCategory.SHORT, VariableType.TWO

    def __init__(self, variable_category: VariableCategory, variable_type: VariableType):
        self.variable_category = variable_category
        self.variable_type = variable_type

    def in_value(self, argument):
        if set(argument).issubset(set(self.value)):
            return self

    @classmethod
    def get_by_values(cls, *args):
        return {member for member in cls
                if member in {member.in_value(arg) for arg in args}}


first = [VariableCategory.SHORT, VariableType.ONE]
second = [VariableCategory.SHORT]

print(*Variable.get_by_values(first, second))
# Variable.A Variable.C

print(*Variable.get_by_values([VariableCategory.MEDIUM]))
# Variable.B

print(*Variable.get_by_values([VariableType.TWO]))
# Variable.B Variable.C
```

**EDIT:** Replaced for's with set comprehensions. The expanded for's section is below:

```py
def in_value(self, argument):

    for element in argument:
        if element not in self.value:
            return False

    return True

@classmethod
def get_by_values(cls, *args):
    result = list()

    for one_member in Variable:
        for argument in args:
            if one_member.in_value(argument):
                if one_member not in result:
                    result.append(one_member)

    return result
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Is there any reason why you prefer `in_value` as you defined it over this?
`def has_value(self, arg):
    return set(arg).issubset(set(self.value))`

This would reduce `get_by_values()` to:

`return {member for member in cls if any({member.has_value(arg) for arg in args})}`

Comment: The exact behavior of the classmethod wasn't entirely specified (you focused on wanting a single method). Is it supposed to receive one condition or several? In how many arguments? Need the response satisfy all conditions, or just one? Should one condition not be satisfied, do you want an ordered list with an empty element? So it depended on requirements, I left `in_value` as a suggestion towards coupling an instance method with the classmethod, should you want an empty element in a list or not add to a set (it's general in this later sense).

Answer (score 2):

```
    @classmethod
    def by_x(cls, criterion):
        return [
                m
                for m in cls
                if m.variable_category == criterion
                    or m.variable_type == criterion
                    ]
```

As an aside, you cannot assign to `self.name` -- it raises an `AttributeError`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the hint! Do you have any other more generic idea? For two fields, this is quite feasible, but say I had 20 fields, this would become cumbersome.